# Doctrine $record->get() with a JOIN

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using the following piece of code to retrieve the tags of a shop:

```
$tags = $this->getObject()->get('Tag');
```

`$this->getObject()` returns a `Shop` object, and `->get('Tag')` returns an array of `Tag` objects related to this shop.

Here's how my database is arranged: 1 `Shop` = 1 or more `Tag`, and 1 `Tag` = 1 `Tag_Translation`.

What i'd like to do is to retrieve, instead of an array of `Tag` objects, and array of `Tag` objects with their translations (in other words, a kind of JOIN).

How is that possible, keeping that same syntax? Thank you very much, i'm new to Doctrine and ORMs in general, i would have had no problem doing it with MySQL but here ...

Comment: I think you'll have to write some dql to achieve this. Here is the doc : http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Answer (score 0):

You may solve this issue like this

a) You can call Tag Models function, when you need the translation

```
$tag->getTagTranslation()
```

b) Or you can overwrite your Shop's getTag() function and build your own Query with DQL as @greg0ire suggested, to fetch translation and tag at once

```
public function getTag(){
    return Doctrine_Query::create()
           ->from("Tag t")
           ->leftJoin("t.TagTranslation tt")
           ->addWhere("t.shop_id = ?", $this->getId())
}
```

(Of course you can name a new function e.g. getTagsWithTranslation())

This assumes, you have built a schema.yml with proper relations !